# Libertinus font on ubuntu, installed version vs. github version

Tags: fontspec, typography, ligatures, libertinus

I'm using the libertinus font family with the latest version coming from [github](https://github.com/libertinus-fonts/libertinus). However, the font is also installed on my system, but I stopped using this version since there was a problem with the math font, which I must say I forgot about (there is a question about that on this site).
Until now I had no problems with that, but I noticed that some ligatures are missing in the github version (for example T_h). I looked into the font files with FontForge and it seems to me that the font is actually missing this ligature as well as others (only the basic ones are present, such as f_i).
Why is this? I would assume that the more recent font version would have, if anything, more ligatures. What happened to them?

Here is an example (I'm compiling with `lualatex main.tex`)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\def\installpath{/path/to/local/fonts}
\setmainfont{LibertinusSerif}[
    UprightFont    = *-Regular,
    BoldFont       = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
    Ligatures      = TeX,
    Extension      = .otf,
    Path           = \installpath/
]
%\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\begin{document}
    Ligatures: ff fi fl ffi fft fb fh fj fk ft Qu Th
\end{document}
```

[image: Example with installed font]
[image: Example with github font]

Comment: How are you compiling?

Comment: Sorry, I've added that to the question. (plain `lualatex main.tex`)

Comment: Good riddance to T_h I say!

Comment: Have you considered opening an issue on github? (Side remark: For me, the existence of the fj ligature is a good reason to be using the Libertinus font, since that combination is frequent in Norwegian. Glad to see it's still there.)

Comment: Hmmm. I just downloaded the latest release from https://github.com/libertinus-fonts/libertinus/releases, and I get the T_h ligature with both `lualatex` and `xelatex`. Interestingly, I get the Q_u ligature with `xelatex`, but *not* with `lualatex`.

Comment: The Q_u ligature can be accessed with `lualatex` by adding `Contextuals=Alternate`. `fontspec` must turn on this feature by default with `xelatex` but not `lualatex`.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Not yet, since I'm assuming the error is on my side. I don't see any good reasons, why the ligatures should vanish. Anyways, I will after some time, if nothing comes up.

Comment: Try adding `Ligatures=Rare`. See https://github.com/libertinus-fonts/libertinus/issues/230 and https://github.com/libertinus-fonts/libertinus/issues/104

Comment: Interesting, I tried again with the font files from the RELEASE and here, as @DavidPurton said, the ligatures are present. The referenced github issues suggest that the ligature handling changed between 6.4 and 6.6, so I don't really understand why the files in the repository are different from the release.

Comment: The Th ligature was moved after the release of 6.6 according to the change log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation at https://github.com/libertinus-fonts/libertinus/blob/master/documentation/Opentype-Features.pdf, the Th ligature is now in the Discretionary ligature set, which is off by default. Note that this also enables (at least) a tz ligature. If you don't want the other ligatures, like tz, then it is also possible to get the Th ligature by putting a Zero Width Joiner (ZWJ) in between. i.e., `T<U200D>h` → `T_h`.

The Qu ligature has been moved to Contextual Alternates, which is supposed to be *on* by default. The fact that this doesn't work by default with `lualatex`, but does with `xelatex` suggests that something is wrong with how `lualatex` or `fontspec` with `lualatex` handles the font.

This should work with the latest files in github (post release 6.6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\begin{document}
Common Ligatures: ff fi fl ffi fft fb fh fj fk ft Qu Th tt tz ck ch

With \verb|ZWJ|: T‍h

\addfontfeatures{Contextuals=Alternate}
With \verb|Contextuals=Alternate|: Qu

\addfontfeatures{Ligatures=Rare}
With \verb|Ligatures=Rare|: Th tt tz ck ch
\end{document}
```

[image: output]